# Can I safely delete minikube.rawdisk?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

[image]

I am trying to free up some space on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Running ncdu shows that minikube is using about 19GB of my /home space. Upon further investigation i see it is the minikube.rawdisk file that is taking up most of the space

[image: Minikube Rawdisk]

Can I delete this file and still have minikube work appropriately. I don't see this as a Linux only question but as a question that can affect the functionality of a Kubernetes service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, if you delete this file, minikube won't be able to run kubernetes anymore.